# Choosing branch to build with latest changes on Jenkins job

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have currently 2 GIT branches, master and develop of a project.
I want to build that branch on single Jenkins job, on which the latest changes are pushed.
Any help or direction will be grateful.

Comment: If pipeline is an option you could try Multibranch pipeline (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/)

Comment: I want to explicitly set rule on a specific branch such that, changes to the specific branch will result in Jenkins execution, not all branches. For eg. trigger on "master" and "develop" only but not on "feature" branch